# how to pass jquery variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095531/passing-javascript-variable-to-php).

My code is basicly the same:

```
<script>
var x=3;

$.ajax({
    url:'ajax.php',
    data: {"x":x}
});
</script>
<?
echo $_REQUEST['x'];
?>
```

But after reading the answer on the previously mentioned link, I still don't know, how can I get it to work?

Please help, thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: And what isn't working exactly? Open your browser console (F12) and check for errors. Make sure error reporting is on in PHP etc.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the returned data from PHP. How do you know it's not working?

Comment: x is undefined index in the php/apache logs and I would just like to print out, to see the 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably working granted that your setup looks like this:

**index.php**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x=3;

    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST', // should probably set this but I think GET is default
        data: {"x":x},
        dataType: 'html', // we expect html from ajax.php
        success: function(data){ // listen for a 200 response from server

            // show the output of ajax.php
            alert(data);

            // send it to the <body>
            $('body').html(data);

        },
        error: function(){

            alert('oh snap! we did not get a 200 response, definitely check the network tab for proper debug');

        }
    });
});
</script>

<body>
</body>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?
echo $_REQUEST['x'];
?>
```

Notice they are separate files.

To debug, make sure you are viewing `index.php`, press F12 and head over to the Network tab, refresh the page, find the HTTP call to `ajax.php` and click it

Comment: I was trying to solve it on the same page...or that won't be possible?

Comment: Possible, yes. Advisable, dear ReligiousFigure NO! Why you ask? Because the success callback would receive the entire javascript and the `echo $_REQUEST;` You can certainly try it but the `alert(data)` will make it crystal clear why you shouldn't.

Comment: Please take a look at the update and notice the `<body>` tag shenanigans

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
var x=3;

$.ajax({
    url:'ajax.php',
    data: { myx : x },
    type: 'post',
});
</script>
<?
echo $_POST['myx'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use GET or POST in your ajax request, otherwise it won't work. So if you POST it to ajax.php, you can use the variable on ajax.php, not on the same page

Comment: So it's not possible to show the passed variable on the same page?